# taking off the http or https off a javascript string

Tags: javascript

I have the following strings

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

how do i get rid of the `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: It may be beside the point, but if your intent is to link to the same scheme as the current location, you can just do `//site.com`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var url = "https://site.com";
var urlNoProtocol = url.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, "");
```

Comment: It works both with http and https. The "s" character is optional.

Comment: I really like how clean this code is. I can't see why your second regexp is necessary... The first one removes the http/https protocol if it is present. If it isn't present there is nothing to replace and the string is returned as is.

Comment: You are right, don't know what I was thinking. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The escape before the colon is unnecessary.  `url.replace(/^https?:\/\//i, "")` is equivalent.

Comment: I'll suggest `.replace(/^\/\/|^.*?:(\/\/)?/, '');` for better cross-protocol support

Answer (score 41):

You can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object like this:

`const urlWithoutProtocol = new URL(url).host;`

Comment: I recommend people upvote this answer a lot, the new URL object functionality is the way to go for a lot of URL handling situations now.

Comment: This will fail on just //site.com

Answer (score 7):

You may use [URL() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL). It will parse your url string and there will be an entry w/o protocol. So less headache with regexps:

```
let u = new URL('https://www.facebook.com/companypage/');
URL {
    hash: ""
    host: "www.facebook.com"
    hostname: "www.facebook.com"
    href: "https://www.facebook.com/companypage/"
    origin: "https://www.facebook.com"
    password: ""
    pathname: "/companypage/"
    port: ""
    protocol: "https:"
    search: ""
    searchParams: URLSearchParams {}
    username: ""
}
u.host // www.facebook.com
u.hostname // www.facebook.com
```

Although `URL()` drops out a protocol, it leaves you with `www` part. In my case I wanted to get rid of that subdomain part as well, so had to use to `.replace()` anyway.

```
u.host.replace(/^www./, '') // www.facebook.com => facebook.com
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var txt="https://site.com";
txt=/^http(s)?:\/\/(.+)$/i.exec(txt);
txt=txt[2];
```

for parsing links without http/https use this:

```
var txt="https://site.com";
txt=/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(.+)$/i.exec(txt);
txt=txt[3];
```

Comment: works great but what about if the string might or might not have http:// some already come in with the format as site.com and on those it fails

Comment: `txt=/(?:https?:\/\/)?(.*)$/i.exec(txt)[1];` No need to capture http or https, using * instead of + so that a string with only https?:// will return an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "https://site.com";

str = str.substr( str.indexOf(':') + 3 );
```

Instead of [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), you could also use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). They'll all produce the same result in this situation.

```
str = str.slice( str.indexOf(':') + 3 );

str = str.substring( str.indexOf(':') + 3 );
```

---

**EDIT:** It appears as though the requirements of the question have changed in a comment under another answer.

If there possibly *isn't* a `http://` in the string, then do this:

```
var str = "site.com";

var index = str.indexOf('://');
if( index > -1 )
   str = str.substr( index + 3 );
```

Comment: I like this one, very simple, and no need for a regex. @Jacob looks like perfectly valid javascript to me?

Comment: will turn "site.com" into "te.com" though...
idx = str.indexOf(':')
if(idx >= 0){
   str = str.substr(idx + 3);
}

Comment: If you want to parse both situations (with http/without) you must use regex, or repeat regex engine work, and make it yourself using string functions. Which is better?

Answer (score 2):

This answer extends some answers above, `http://`, `https://`, **or** `//` which is also common.

Thanks for answers above that led me to this!

```
const urls = [ "http://example.com", "https://example.com", "//example.com" ]

// the regex below states: replace `//` or replace `//` and the 'stuff'
const resolveHostNames = urls.map(url => url.replace(/\/\/|.+\/\//, ''))

console.log(resolveHostNames);
```

Here's a [link to a codepen](https://codepen.io/yowainwright/pen/eydvPv/).

Comment: this is actually the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Strip the protocol from a URL:

```
var url = "https://site.com";
var urlNoProto = url.split('/').slice(2).join('/');
```

Works with any protocol, ftp, http, gopher, nntp, telnet, wais, file, prospero ... all those specified in RFC 1738 with the exception of those without a // in them (mailto, news).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in real web pages **inherited protocol** `//` is a common practice https://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url.

So I suggest regexp covering this case as well:

`/^\/\/|^https?:\/\//`

(you can optimize it)

Answer (score 1):

Another efficient solution,

`url.replace(/(^(\w+:)?\/\//, '')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no double slashes other than the protocol, you could do:

```
 var url = "https://example.com";
 var noProtocol = url.split('//')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use *HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils* of DOM:

```
function removeProtocol(url) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  // `url` may be relative, but `a.href` will be absolute.
  return a.href.replace(a.protocol + '//', '');
}

removeProtocol('https://example.com/https://foo');
// 'example.com/https://foo'

removeProtocol('wrong://bad_example/u');
// 'bad_example/u'
```

From [HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils):

`a.hostname`, *example.com*
`a.host`, *example.com:3000*
`a.pathname`, */foo/bar.html*
`a.search`, *?a=1&b=2*
`a.hash`, *#goo*
`a.username`, `a.password`, `a.port`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex might be an overkill when there's a handy native [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface that does the job for you in 2 lines:

```js
let url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999764/taking-off-the-http-or-https-off-a-javascript-string";
let a = new URL(url);
let withoutProtocol = a.host+a.pathname;
console.log(`Without protocol: ${withoutProtocol}`);
console.log(`With protocol: ${url}`);
```

[URL API Support in browsers](https://caniuse.com/url)

Answer (score -1):

Javascript use of split function also dervies the solution.
Awesome !!!

```
var url = "https://example.com";

url = url.split("://")[1];    // for https use url..split("://")[0];
console.log(url);
```