# React removing url protocol from class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app, I have a button that allows people to create a button that links to a URL. It works except that if you don't add the protocol (HTTP/HTTPS), it doesn't redirect properly.

I looked at the following popular answer here on Stack Overflow: [taking off the http or https off a javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999764/taking-off-the-http-or-https-off-a-javascript-string)

*Top Answer*

```
var url = "https : // site.com"; 
var urlNoProtocol = url.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, "");
```

and tried implementing it into my onChange function:

#### UrlButton.jsx

```
  onChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    let pattern = new RegExp(
      '^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // protocol
      '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
      '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
      '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
      '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
      '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$',
      'i'
    ); // fragment locator
    // console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    // console.log(pattern.test(e.target.value));
    if (pattern.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
  };
```

I'm using the onChange function like this:

```
 <form onClick={this.onSubmit}>
              <input
                className="url-input"
                name="title"
                type="text"
                placeholder="add button text"
                onChange={e => this.setState({ title: e.target.value })}
              />
              <input
                className="url-input"
                name="url"
                type="url"
                value={this.url}
                placeholder="your-link.com"
                onBlur={e => {
                  this.props.onChange({
                    target: {
                      id: this.props.id,
                      link: e.target.value,
                      value: this.state.title,
                    },
                  });
                  this.setState({ url: e.target.value });
                }}
              />
            </form>
```

The current answer has the Javascript `replace()` method which is missing from my onChange function. How would I implement this within my function? I'm still a novice, so I'm not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to remove a matched pattern, just use `string.replace(regex, '')`

Comment: This code sets state only if the url satifies your regex condition.So why do you want to replace. What is your need?

Comment: @Dipesh for user convenience. Most people don't type out the protocol when they are going to a website. They'll type ```stackoverflow.com``` instead of ```https://stackoverflow.com``` into their browser. I found the error because I was doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UrlButton.jsx**

```
onChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    let pattern = new RegExp('^https?://')
    if (pattern.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
    else{
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: 'https://'+e.target.value });
    }};
```

**Form**

```
 <form onClick={this.onSubmit}>
              <input
                className="url-input"
                name="title"
                type="text"
                placeholder="add button text"
                onChange={e => this.setState({ title: e.target.value })}
              />
              <input
                className="url-input"
                name="url"
                type="url"
                value={this.url}
                placeholder="your-link.com"
                onBlur={e => {
                  this.props.onChange({
                    target: {

                      value:  e.target.value,
                      name:'url'
                    },
                  });

                }}
              />
            </form>
```

Comment: Yes, you understood the question correctly. It isn't working but only because I didn't understand one thing. I removed ``` this.setState({ url: e.target.value });``` from my input, but I don't understand where I should add this: "you need to send 'name' in your target object"

Comment: You have 2 inputs.Which input holds url?

Comment: The bottom input is for the URL. The top input is for creating a button name like "visit my website".

Comment: I have updated my answer.Let me know if anything go wrong :)